# Randomly images in ListActivity

Tags: android, image, random, listactivity

In my ListActivity I use this CursorAdapter, but there is problem with randomly images, how can I fix it ?

```
public class TopCallAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void bindView(View oldView, Context ctx, Cursor c)
    {
        ...

        int bmpUriIndex = c.getColumnIndex(C.BITMAP_URI);
        String bmpUriStr = c.getString(bmpUriIndex);
        if(bmpUriStr != null && bmpUriStr != "") {
            Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(bmpUriStr);

            ImageView image = (ImageView) oldView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageURI(bmpUri);
        }
    }
}
```

.. after i scroll, images appear randomly. THX for all help.

Comment: `if(..) {... } ` **`else { image.setEmptyImageSomehow() }`**

Comment: To explain Selvin's comment a bit: Android reuses item views in ListViews and gives you the old item via the oldView parameter. This is a fully initialized item containing a prior image. So if you do not change the image, you get whatever image was in that recycled item view before.

Comment: It's work.
 else {image.setImageDrawable(null);}
Thanks